# php activerecord getting instance property via one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, ruby, activerecord, foreach

I have 3 ActiveRecord  models.

Cat (category), Subcat (subcategory) and Content.

The relationship between these models are

```
//category
class Cat extends ActiveRecord\Model {
  ...
    static $has_many = array(
    array('subcats')
    );

// subcategory
class Subcat extends ActiveRecord\Model {

  static $has_many = array(
        array('contents')
      );
  static $belongs_to = array(
        array('cat')
      );
//content
class Content extends ActiveRecord\Model {

static $belongs_to = array(
    array('subcat')
    );
```

Php ActiveRecord is not enoough smart to handle singular/plurals as Rails' ActiveRecord, this is why I gave these weird class names :)

Subcat and Content class instances have image attribute (actually image_path). For a gallery (or slider, whatever it is) I need to select random images for `Cat` instances. I decided to use random images from subcats which `belongs to` `this` cat. Or from contents which `belongs to` `subcat` which `belongs to` this cat.

A ruby equivalent seems like that (inside a Cat class).

```
def random_image 
    this_cats_images_array = []
    self.subcats.each {|s| this_cats_images_array << s.image_path }
    random_image = this_cats_images_array.sample #or shuffle then sample
    return random_image
end
```

How can I rewrite the php equivalent of above (or more improved :) ) ruby code?

I actually tried to declare randomimage() function inside `Cat` class.

```
public function randomimage() {

$desired_array = array();
foreach ($this->subcats as $sc) { //changed $this->subcats->contents
     array_push($desired_array, $sc->image_path)
}
return $desired_array[array_rand($desired_array)];
}
```

But when I try to call it inside view file like,

```
            <img src="assets/uploads/<?php echo $cats_on_sld[$i]->randomimage(); ?>" alt="">
```

it doesn't show anything and when i view the source of page there is such error:

```
<img src="assets/uploads/
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/adminpanel/models/Cat.php on line 14

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/adminpanel/models/Cat.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index:  in /var/www/adminpanel/models/Cat.php on line 17
" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited the code and everything is now, ok. There was a logical problem. `$cats->subcats->contents` was not a meaningful expression. I've cut out the last and iterated over `$cats->subcats` `as $sc`.